# What is LLAWP ? How to Check the status of LLAWP?

Tags: linux, redhat, websphere, ibmhttpserver

I have installed IBM HTTP Server and Apache Tomcat in my RHEL linux. In my linux how to check the status of LLAWP. I used this code to check the status      `ps -ef|grep LLAWP`. but it returns only pid, name, user. I need status whether is running or stopped

Comment: Is theis RHEL 6 or RHEL7 ? How do you start the service ?

Comment: RHEL 7. For IBM HTTP server is used /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/apachectl start. For Tomcat startup.sh

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it's actually returning anything, then this process is running.
If the process is not running, you will get no output.

Comment: if it returns anything exit code is '0'. Am i right?

Comment: how to check it returns anything or nothing in linux? need check 'null' value or '0'

Comment: Its now works fine. I used below code to check the status of LLAWP

`llawp=ps -ef | grep LLAWP
status=echo $?
if [ $status = 0 ];
then
 echo "LLAWP is running....."
elif [ $status = 1 || $status = 2 ] ;
then
 echo "LLAWP is not running...."
fi

Answer (score 1):

There may be other ways (systemctl status ...) but I'm not familiar with the specific services you are using so

- For apache

  /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/apachectl status

should return 0 if httpd is running and something else (3) if not.

For tomcat there is an answer on [so] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944157/is-tomcat-running

Answer (score 0):

LLAWP is a sidecar process launched by Computer Associates Siteminder product.  It's not actually part of IHS or Tomcat, but supporting software for Siteminder.

As others have said, if you can find it's PID, it's obviously running and not stopped!